# Оплата в телебот нескольких товаров сразу через юкассу

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, платежи

Проблема заключается в том, что я могу принять оплату на 1 товар в заказе. Но когда я пытаюсь суммироыать (любым способом) цены на несколько товаров, то ничего не выходит. Только телеграм машет пальчиком и говорит об ошибке. Может быть кто то знает как это сделать или сталкивался с этим?

Comment: Приведите ваш код **прямо в вопросе**.